# Why does heap memory increase without bound when the main JS thread receives messages from a web worker every 50ms and simply console.logs it?

Tags: javascript

**Issue**: simply sending messages from a web worker to the main thread every 50ms and console logging the messages leads to increasing usage of heap memory without bound.

I have created [an example github repo](https://github.com/bolkonsky-ryazan/webworkers-ex) for this question with which you can reproduce this issue.

Here is a description of what is in that project:

- a file `server.js` which runs a very simple websocket server that on connection simply starts sending messages each 50ms. The messages are a big data object with a bunch of numbers (6000 of them) sampled from a normal distribution.
- an `index.html` file that loads a script called `main.js`
- `main.js` loads a web worker from a file `worker.js`, and sends a message to it to tell it to connect to the websocket server that will generate the data every 50ms.
- `worker.js` upon receiving the first message connects to the websocket server, and starts receiving the messages with numbers every 50ms. It processes the message by transforming the data, and then sends it to `main.js`.
- `main.js` upon receiving data just console.logs it.

If with this setup you open the devtools and profile the app, you will see that heap usage goes up visually ike a staircase: each time the main thread processes a message from the web worker, heap increases. Occasionally there is garbage collection but it only decreases usage only partially.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the memory profile].

[image: Here is a screenshot of the memory profile when there is no console log] in the main.js file, ie, when the main thread receives the message from the web worker but does absolutely nothing with it, not even console logging it. It looks like it should look, no memory issue and garbage collection taking care of things.

**Why does heap go up without bound when there is the console log in the main thread?**

Comment: does it really goes without bounds? it seems it have GC'd once so probably would GC again.

Comment: well, until there is no more memory left then it stops

Comment: console.log keeps reference

Comment: In reality I don't want to just console log of course, I want to do other things with the data on the main thread. This is just the minimal example I came up with.

Comment: But logging it may indeed keep reference to the objects preventing the GC to do its job. If your code doesn't need to keep these objects in memory, then it shouldn't keep references to it, and the issue you are facing is actually not an issue. If your code needs to keep these objects accessible though, you have a design problem.

Comment: I don't keep references, so you are right I don't experience the issue in my real code.

Answer (score 1):

The browser needs to keep references to everything that is `console.log`ged to be able to display it later. That is also why a round of GC does nothing, and why removing the `console.log` call fixes it.